# Pulling full content of a tweet

Tags: twitter, google-apps-script

So, I have a program where I'm trying to pull the full content of an extended tweet on a regular basis. The problem is, since the change to 280 characters I can only access the first half of the tweet. The start of my code is:

```
function refreshing_v2() {



var service = getTwitterService();



if (service.hasAccess()) {

var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=(redacted)&count=1&include_rts=0&exclude_replies=1';

var response = service.fetch(url);
var tweets = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {

  //Parse the tweet
  var latest = new String(tweets[i].text);
```

The problem being that this returns (first half of the tweet text)...(link to tweet) instead of the full tweet text. I have tried changing latest's call from .text to .full_text, but that just returns undefined because the tweet is truncated already at the "tweets" variable. Is there an easy thing I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the extended tweets, as long as you're using a REST api, you can add the parameter `tweet_mode=extended` to any endpoint, then you should be able to replace `text` with `full_text`. If the parameter tweet_mode parameter isn't provided, it defaults to the 140 character compatibility mode.

Source: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates

Comment: You're a gem. I tried each of those things individually and somehow it didn't occur to me to try them together.